# SQL selecting error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT f.flight_id 
FROM flights f 
JOIN flightsinfo AS i ON f.flight_code = i.flight_code
JOIN airports AS a ON i.dep_airport_id = a.airport_id 
JOIN cities as c ON a.city_id = c.city_id AND city_name = 'New York'
JOIN airports AS b ON i.arr_airport_id = b.airport_id
JOIN cities AS v ON v.city_id = b.city_id AND v.city_name = 'Budapest'
HAVING f.price = MIN(price)
```

I'm trying to get the `flight_id` of a flight with minimal price between two random cities. Error occurs on the last line

> unknown column in having clause

When I try to use where/from error says:

> Invalid use of group function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't have a "naked" aggregate function, such as `min`, in the `where` clause.

Comment: you could just  `Select top 1 order by f.price`

Comment: Did you try: having f.price = min(f.price)

Comment: Please tag dbms used. The answer may depend on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need the first record based on an order, just use `SELECT TOP 1` or `TAKE 1` depending on rdbms, and order by the field you need ordered.

**SQL SERVER 2008**

```
SELECT TOP 1
    f.flight_id
FROM
    flights f
    JOIN flightsinfo AS i ON f.flight_code = i.flight_code
    JOIN airports AS a ON i.dep_airport_id = a.airport_id
    JOIN cities AS c ON a.city_id = c.city_id
                        AND city_name = 'New York'
    JOIN airports AS b ON i.arr_airport_id = b.airport_id
    JOIN cities AS v ON v.city_id = b.city_id
                        AND v.city_name = 'Budapest'
ORDER BY 
    f.price
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT 
    f.flight_id
FROM
    flights AS f
    JOIN flightsinfo AS i ON f.flight_code = i.flight_code
    JOIN airports AS a ON i.dep_airport_id = a.airport_id
    JOIN cities AS c ON a.city_id = c.city_id
                        AND city_name = 'New York'
    JOIN airports AS b ON i.arr_airport_id = b.airport_id
    JOIN cities AS v ON v.city_id = b.city_id
                        AND v.city_name = 'Budapest'
ORDER BY 
    f.price
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a common table expression (cte) to find flights having the lowest price. (Will return both flights if it's a tie.)

```
WITH CTE (flight_id, price) AS
(
SELECT f.flight_id, f.price
FROM flights f 
JOIN flightsinfo AS i ON f.flight_code = i.flight_code
JOIN airports AS a ON i.dep_airport_id = a.airport_id 
JOIN cities as c ON a.city_id = c.city_id AND city_name = 'New York'
JOIN airports AS b ON i.arr_airport_id = b.airport_id
JOIN cities AS v ON v.city_id = b.city_id AND v.city_name = 'Budapest'
)
select flight_id, price
from cte
where price = (select min(price) from cte)
```

Alternatively, the ANSI SQL version of JamieD77's answer:

```
SELECT 
    f.flight_id
FROM
    flights AS f
    JOIN flightsinfo AS i ON f.flight_code = i.flight_code
    JOIN airports AS a ON i.dep_airport_id = a.airport_id
    JOIN cities AS c ON a.city_id = c.city_id
                        AND city_name = 'New York'
    JOIN airports AS b ON i.arr_airport_id = b.airport_id
    JOIN cities AS v ON v.city_id = b.city_id
                        AND v.city_name = 'Budapest'
ORDER BY 
    f.price
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

The `WITH TIES` means that several rows will be returned if it's a tie!